# Rolling pct_change function over a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to edit `series.rolling('30d').pct_change()` (which doesn't work) to roll `pandas.DataFrame.pct_change` over a `pandas.DatetimeIndex`?

I have a series with a DatetimeIndex and I would like to calculate the 1 month change in percentage.

To do that I could use pct_change(period=30) but it is not as accurate as a rolling(‘30d’), which doesn’t fit with the pct_change() function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Comment: Mayby you should first `resample` it to '30D' (30days) or '1M'(1month), then do `pct_change`. Like this: `series.resample('1M').last().pct_change()`. Also make sure your series has `DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: @Ian thanks Ian. Should’ve reply as an answer.